# Molecule fails with "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result"

Tags: ansible-2.x, molecule

I am using Ansible with Molecule. I just ran into the situation that converging my role failed with:

```
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result"}
```

How to mitigate? Hold on a sec, I will answer ...

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is to set logging to "true" for molecule:

1. Go to the "molecule.yml" file, this is where you do your configuration for molecule.
   You should find it in the `molecule/default/` directory
2. Look for the `provisioner:` section
3. Add `log: true` to it.
4. Voilà!

That's how it looks:

```
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  log: true
```

Note that there may by other settings in this very section for the provisioner.

Comment: To be honest: Probably just editing the file did the trick. After removing the logging parameter, the error also went away. I am still a bit fuzzy here, so please excuse.

Comment: Upvoted the answer since it answers the question. I didn't have log output. I made the change. Now I do!